# Preflop Pot Odds

Tags: nlhe, pre-flop, pot-odds

Is there a minimum pot odd required where it would be profitable to call with ANY 2 cards preflop?

I'm thinking of multiple limpers on SB, or a clickraise (with multiple callers) on BB.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how deep the stacks are and how many players are involved in the pot. To make this easier lets suppose you have 72o, since it is the bottom of your pre-flop range.

If you have to **call an all-in** in a **heads-up pot** with 72o you are never really more than a 11% dog. Calling while getting around 8 : 1 can NEVER be bad. If your opponent is shoving top 10% of hands however, you have 25% equity, so you should call if you are getting 3 : 1.

If you have to **call an all-in** in a **multi-way pot** your chances drop. It depends on the range of your opponents, but usually you have around 15% in equity, which means you should be calling if you are getting around 5 : 1.

Spots were you have to call all-ins can easily be answered by sites like:
 [*propokertools*](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations)

If the stacks are **more deep** this changes. In a **heads-up pot** you will need a lot more than 3 : 1, since your hand plays terrible post flop. It is very hard to play your hand. You are basically hoping for 2 pair, but you still aren't crushing an overpair. Or trips and even then you can still be outkicked sometimes. The reversed implied odds are very big. Since you will never really be getting a much better price than 3 : 1 pre-flop in a heads-up situation, you cannot defend any two cards. Your bottom range should probably be a hand like 96o, Q2s or 43s if you want to play like a loose maniac.

In a **multi-way pot** with **deep stacks** the reversed implied odds are even bigger. The more people, the better the price, but also the bigger the reversed implied odds. Therefore you will never be getting the right price to call. Your bottom range in a multiway pot should  probably be more towards low suited connectors, since they have better equity and playability on later streets.

To conclude: if the stacks are deep there will not be any spots in which you can call 100% of hands, since you are never getting the right price and the reversed implied odds can be big. In all-in spots you can use sites like [*propokertools*](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations) to figure out whether you should be calling or not.

Comment: To clarify, you would recommend 10:1 pot odds to call with a random hand, but you would rather not play hands such as 27o (i suppose 25o - 28o in that range), as they have heavy reverse implied odds?

Comment: @sakon that is the part where I am talking about calling an all-in. Then reversed implied odds don't play a roll

Comment: @sakon but indeed my answer wasn't really clear, I updated it, thanks!

Comment: Heads up 72o is 13% (6.7 : 1) to AA and it is impossible to get 4.2 : 1 pot odds pre heads up.   The best pot odds you can pre heads up  get 3:1.  If opponent shoves to 10 bb then only getting 1.2 : 1 - cannot call that even if your hand is only a 3 : 1 dog.

Comment: @Paparazzi worst possible hand to be up against isn't 13% but 11%. However, I was wrong thanks for improving my answer.

Comment: 72 AA is 13% by tool you link.   Your answer is still wrong.  Best pot odds you can get pre heads up is 3:1.  You will NEVER have an opportunity to call getting 8:1.

Comment: @paparazzi you can simulate 7s2h vs 8s8h for 89%-11%. 3.1 : 1 is around 3 : 1, but once again thanks for the input and I updated my answer. And finally, you will sometimes get the opportunity to call getting 8 : 1. Suppose your are in the BB versus a button shove for 1.1 blinds.

Comment: Your answer is they only have one chip behind and shove?  That would be 5:1 and they will be shoving with any two cards so yes you should call.    11% is not anywhere close to to 3:1.

Answer (score 0):

Assume any pot odds means worst possible hand to hand match up.

AA is best possible hand.
There are some weird match ups that AA is not the best but just take AA as best.

Worst possible hand is 72o

Heads up 72o is still worst statistically. In reality a lot of people consider 32o worst as your opponent for sure is playing any pocket pair.

Basically worst plausible match up you are a 7:1 dog.  You are about 7:1 dog to any over pair.  Best you are hoping for is 2 overs for a 2:1 dog.  You are a 2:1 dog to even a random hand.

Can only consider pot odds versus hand odds pre flop for all in as if not all in then facing future streets.  This would be you or opponent all in.  SB can have some unique situations but I am only looking at BB.

Head up BB facing an all in raise

```
Chip    Pot
Raise   Odds  
1       5.00
2       3.00
3       2.33
4       2.00
5       1.80
6       1.67
7       1.57
8       1.50
9       1.44
10      1.40
11      1.36
12      1.33
13      1.31
14      1.29
15      1.27
16      1.25
17      1.24
18      1.22
19      1.21
20      1.20
```

Pre flop you are never getting 7:1 but that does not mean you should never call.  When you get really short stacked you need to call based on blind structure.

BB technically should not call off 1 chip raise getting 5:1 with hand odds of 7:1 but BB is calling off a 1 chip raise because BB should call off a 1 chip raise in that spot without looking at the cards.

BB technically should not call off a 2 chip (1 BB) raise getting 3:1 possibly facing hand odds of 7:1.  BB is calling off that raise because BB should do so without looking at the cards.

All the way up to 4 chips (2 BB) raise BB needs to call it off without even looking at the cards.  You are getting odds to call 2 over cards.

Even against a random hand 32o and 72o cannot call off 3 BB raise.  For sure cannot call off a premium hand.

When you get really short stacked (less than 10 bigs) then just play the push fold charts.

Comment: You are saying you can never call with 72o if you are getting 3:1 on your money, because against the worst possible hand you are a 6.7:1 dog. But this is certainly incorrect logic, since your opponent will have a range of hands, instead of this particular hand. If you look at a top 10% range, even 72o still has 30% equity. Therefore it is not a fold, but a clear call.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans  Comments are not for discussion.  I see you have an answer.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans The question is not what I would call with.   The question is can I get odds to call with any two card.  For *any* I have to assume I have the worst cards and opponent(s) have best.

Comment: no that is simply wrong. Calling with any two means that you can profitably call with any two, which means you are getting the right price versus a certain range.

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Means that to *you*.   I clearly state in my answer I am looking at worse possible match up.

Comment: however, you should be answering the question. I quote "where it would be profitable to call with ANY 2 cards preflop"

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans  ANY means the ANY can be worse.  I will answer the question as I read it and state my assumptions thank you.  If ANY meant the opponent could haven ANY then they could have my exact hand and I should call every time.